# What maths is shown in this image?

Tags: linear-algebra

It relates to engineering calculations, but the brackets are confusing me - isn't it simpler to just write e.g. `P x P'` instead of `P(P')`?. The apostrophe outside the last bracket in `(EI)(EI)` also confuses me.

Unfortunately where delta comes from is not shown.

[image]

Comment: We cannot just guess what all that means... At the very least, you ought to tell us where the image comes from, for example. How could be know where delta comes from if we do not know where *anything else* comes from? We are good, you know, but we have limits!

Comment: Could it be a confusing way to write the two equations $\delta=PL^3/3EI$ and $\delta'=P'L'^3/3(EI)'$ at once? It's hard to say without any further context.

Comment: I think my last comment must be right because those are the equations for the deflection of a beam with a single support and a force P acting at one end. Young's modulus is the stress-strain ratio and is often written E, so that fits with the other pair of equations.

Comment: @MatthewTowers, I think you could be right; I'm afraid I don't know the source of the image - it was posted in a discussion about forces acting on tree stems/crowns, and how to calculate the strength of a support brace between two tree stems.

Comment: @MatthewTowers so would that mean that, in this image, EI and E are the same thing (modulus of elasticity)?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez good point, I've added more explanation in my reply to Matthew Towers, but unfortunately I don't have more info.

Comment: No, I would be the moment of inertia and E the Young's modulus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe do not seem to indicate a derivative or a mathematical operation of any sort, but rather a notation discerning the two trunks and their respective characteristics given by the various variables (whose nature we deduce below).

In fact, this seems to be an application of Euler's (he is everywhere, isn't he?!) [Critical load formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_critical_load)

$$P_{cr}=\frac{\pi^2EI}{(KL)^2}$$

Combined with the following image obtained from the paper-

*Chiba, Y. (2000). Modelling stem breakage caused by typhoons in plantation Cryptomeria japonica forests. Forest Ecology and Management, 135(1-3), 123–131. doi:10.1016/s0378-1127(00)00304-2* :

[image]

allows us to make the fair assumption that$:$

$P:\text{crown load}$

$P_{cr}:\text{critical crown load}$

$\delta:\text{deflection at the action point of
the stem from the vertical}$

$L:\text{length of column(tree trunk)}$

$E:\text{Young's modulus}$

$I:\text{minimum second moment of area }$

while $\sigma$ is the [yield strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_critical_load#Assumptions_of_the_model) given by $$\sigma=\frac{P_{cr}}{A}$$

where $A$ is the area cross section (of the trunk presumably).

This information should be enough to deduce the relationships displayed on the OP's problem.